# Internal Web Server Certificate is not getting validated in Chrome

Tags: windows

We have On Premises Microsoft PKI Environment. Using INternal CA we issued Web server certificate to a internal website. This certificate has been installed in Web Server IIS and completed binding to the site.

While connecting to site, Certificate is valid in Explorer but it is showing invalid in Chrome.
How can I make this certificate truted

Comment: You're going to need to post additional detail in order for people to help you. What exact error does Chrome show? What version is Chrome? What OS is it running on? What are the details of the certificate you created? What OS is the IIS server? Have you made any changes to the default TLS config in the OS?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the domain name is not listed in the "Subject Alternative Name" (SAN) field of the certificate, and it's mandatory since Chrome 58 : https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9813310?hl=en#private

> Some public key infrastructures (PKIs), legacy systems, and older
>   versions of network monitoring software use certificates without
>   subjectAlternativeName extensions. If you’re having issues with any of
>   these, contact the software vendor or administrator and ask them to
>   generate a new certificate.
>
> For Microsoft® Windows®, you can use the PowerShell Cmdlet
>   New-SelfSignedCertificate and specify the DnsName parameter.
>
> For OpenSSL, you can use the subjectAltName extension to specify the
>   subject alternative name.